# Find index of array with array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've found some good answers about how getting an index of an array with `indexOf`. However, this doesn't suit me since I must return the the index of the parent array that contains a child array which contains an object with certain id.

This would be a sample array:

```
[
    [{id: 1}],
    [{id: 2}],
    [
        {id: 3}
        {id: 4}
    ],
    [
        {id: 5},
        {id: 6}
    ],
    [{id: 7}],
]
```

For example, if I'd like to find the index of the `id : 4` the index would be `2`.

I've thought about a `map` inside the `findIndex` method:

```
array.findIndex((el) => el.map((e) => e.id === noteId )));
```

But have not found much success yet.

Comment: Map doesn't return true/false. `array.findIndex((el) => el.some((e) => e.id === noteId )));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andy Ray commented, a map doesnt return a true value.

so the correct way to do it is this:

`array.findIndex((el) => el.some((e) => e.id === noteId )));`

```js
const array = [
    [{id: 1}],
    [{id: 2}],
    [
        {id: 3},
        {id: 4},
    ],
    [
        {id: 5},
        {id: 6}
    ],
    [{id: 7}],
]

const noteId = 3;

console.log(array.findIndex((el) => el.some((e) => e.id === noteId )));
```